# Retrieving custom claims Firebase/React immediately after authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to request custom claims as soon as my React app loads, and the user has been authorized.

Here is my code:

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  const [claims, setClaims] = useState({})
  const [isCustomClaimRequested, setIsCustomClaimRequested] = useState(false)


  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
    setUser(currentUser)
    if(currentUser) {
      localStorage.setItem("signedIn", "true")
      if ( !isCustomClaimRequested ) {
        setIsCustomClaimRequested(true)
        auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
          setClaims(idTokenResult.claims)
          console.log("userCustomClaims", claims)
        })
      }
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("signedIn")
    }
  })
```

Currently, when I run this code, the console logs:

```
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
userCustomClaims  {}
```

Which means that it is calling `getIDTokenResult()` 8 times. But it does work to retrieve the custom claims.

How can I make the request for the custom claims only once, after the user is authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

I just moved it to `useEffect` and that fixed it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCustomClaimRequested) {
      auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
        .then((tokenResult) => {
          if (tokenResult.claims) {
            setClaims(tokenResult.claims)
          }
        })

    }
  }, [isCustomClaimRequested])
```